How often do Bonus Picks occur?
In this days an event is ongoing, and sometimes you can find free Bonus Picks in Wonder Pick page. They seem to last for an hour and then come back later.
Is there a fixed schedule for them to appear? How many Bonus Picks are supposed to happen in a day? I've got 3 free Bonus Pick and 1 (paid) Rare Pick so far.
EDIT:
An Extra Pick just spawned, this makes 5 events per day.

According to this guide, bonus picks randomly appear whenever a standard wonder pick expires.

There is a chance for a Bonus Pick to spawn after an old Wonder Pick expires. The best way to keep track is to set a timer for your oldest Wonder Pick and check back if any event picks pop up.
Once you see a Bonus Pick in your Wonder Pick menu, either a 30-minute countdown timer or a 60-minute countdown timer for it will start. After this countdown, the Bonus Pick will disappear if you don’t pick from it.


Cool. Need to check this before accepting

Since the timer always starts when you see the Bonus Pick alert it's hard to track them. But ok this might be true, because there are several Wonder Picks that run out each hour, and sometimes a new one appears as a special version.
